# Automating Export of MS SQL Table with a binary column (750,000 character length)

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, ssms

This may or may not be possible. I know sqlcmd could be used to export tables from MS SQL to a csv but my column gets truncated at ~ 65,000 characters.

Is there a way to automate the process of exporting a table from MS SQL which has strings with length upto 750,000 (binary data).

Using SSMS 2008.

Thanks,
F

Answer (score 1):

SSMSBoost add-in that I develop has functionality to script full data using flexible templating mechanism. You can script data as XML, text or Excel-compatible format. Currently we script only data from results grid (no worry, data will not be truncated).
But it is not a command-line way of export.